Can complex integration be realized as an analytic continuation of real integration?
I'm trying to motivate the definition of complex integration in a short document about complex analysis I'm writing. In it, I've taken the view which identifies the complex numbers both with conformal transformations of the plane and with the plane itself (with extra algebraic structure), because I felt like it illuminated the definitions of complex differentiability better. I don't want to get into those kinds of subjective discussions here, however, this left me in an awkward position regarding complex integration. Because I've made so many parallels between complex analysis and real analysis in the plane, it struck me that a natural question to ask would be "why don't we just imbue $\mathbb{C}$ with the cartesian inner product and integrate along a curve", as in, $$I'=\int_{\gamma} f :=\int_{[a,b]}(u,v)\cdot\gamma' dt$$
where $f=(u,v)\cong u+iv$.
Now, I can come up with several reasons as to why this option isn't interesting (e.g, the integral would always be real-valued, Cauchy's integral theorem wouldn't be true, this definition is agnostic about the algebra of the complex numbers, etc...) but I wanted to think about it a little bit more to see if I can motivate better $$I=\int_{\gamma} f dz:=\int_{\gamma} (u+iv)(dx+idy)=\int_{\gamma} (u,-v)+i \int_{\gamma} (v,u)$$
I realize that this latter definition can be achieved by a Riemann-like construction but substituting the inner product with the curve's velocity by complex multiplication, but I wonder: can it be achieved by analytical continuation of $\mathbb{R}$ integration?
To be clear, what I'm asking is the following.
Let $\mathscr{R}: F([a,b],\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $F([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ is the space of real integrable functions in $[a,b]$, be the Riemann integral. Let $f$ be such a function, and $\tilde{f}$ its analytical continuation into the complex numbers, i.e, a holomorphic function s.t $\tilde{f}|_{\mathbb{R}}=f$. Is there an "analytical continuation" $\tilde{\mathscr{R}}_{\gamma}: F(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t $\tilde{\mathscr{R}}_{\gamma}\tilde{f}|_{\mathbb{R}}=\mathscr{R}f$ and $\tilde{\mathscr{R}}_{\gamma}\tilde{f}=I$ ($\gamma$ is any curve that contains the inclusion of $[a,b]$ in the complex numbers)?
The problem is, I don't know if this has any rigorous meaning, e.g, what is the sense in saying that $\mathscr{R}_{\gamma}$ analytically continues $I$; is there even a holomorphic structure on the functionals on complex functions? Furthermore, the fact that $\mathscr{R}_{\gamma}$ depends on the curve, and there are infinitely many curves that contain $[a,b]$, would mean that if this "analytical continuation" exists then it is not unique, which doesn't sound like it helps me very much.
So, in conclusion, and assuming I expressed the countours of the idea well, has work been done on something like this, even if the finer details of the idea don't seem to work out quite well? I would also appreciate some comments on other ways to motivate the complex integration definition.

"Real integrable functions" do not come with an "analytical continuation". To have an analytic continuation, a function must be analytic itself, that is, representable as a power series. This does not hold for the vast majority of integrable functions. But, I really don't see the problem you are trying to solve. The only reason real path integration uses the inner product is that this is the only product available between two vectors. But in $\Bbb C$, there a different, far more obvious, product. What could be more natural than using it?

@PaulSinclair I guess so, but in this case what would need to be analytic (in some suitable sense which I'm not even sure exists) would be the integral operator itself, not the measurable functions. About your last point, yeah, you're probably right, and that's enough reason to motivate it. Still, I'd like to see if there are different ways.
